# passing received array as pointer in a function and passing it to another function C

Tags: c

I have main, func1 and `getr_seq()` functions. What I am doing is I am getting arrays in func1 like this `int func1(char *arr,int n,char *array)`

```
arr=with string
n=sizeof arr
array=result // assumed n size initially
return=sizeof result
```

But from func1 to `getr_seq` I dont know how to pass array and received it as pointer in `getr_seq`.

this is I tried

```
int func1(char *arr,int n,char *array)
{
...
int ret=getr_seq(&arr,n,mid,array,0);
return ret;
}
```

in getr_seq I am getting arrays like this `int getr_seq(char *arr,int n,int mid,char *array,int length)` ret is the actual required sizeof result array named `array`

```
int getr_seq(char *arr,int n,int mid,char *array,int length)
{...,...
     return int_var;//size of array=int_var
}
```

and in main I am calling it like this `func1(arr,n,array);` arr and array are string and required result respectively and n is the sizeof `arr`. return of getr_seq is the actual sizeof array `array` (4th parameter)

```
main 

void main()
{
    char arr[10]="abcdeabcde";
    int n=strlen(arr);
        char array[n];
//  func1(char *arr,int n,char *array)
    int ret=func1(arr,n,array);
    
    

}
```

getr_seq suppose to populate array named `array` after checking array named `arr`

basically I need to pass array and arr from main to func1 to getr_seq functions and received the outcome which should be more than 0 `ret` val

But return from `func1` to main is 0 in all cases because I did not pass the received array in function(func1) to another function (getr_seq)

basically I have created a repeated pattern find-out function based on two functions `func1` and `getr_seq`. with loop in main and only `getr_seq` function (no mid func1 function) the program works fine. but when I bring in middle function it doesn't.

`int ret=getr_seq(&arr,n,mid,array,0);` cause

passing argument 1 of ‘getr_seq’ from incompatible pointer type [

Comment: `ret=getr_seq(&arr,n,mid,array,0)` argument 4 does not look correct either

Comment: argument 1 should be `arr` not `&arr`.

Comment: No then it still does not work as needed

Comment: are you still getting `passing argument 1 of ‘getr_seq’ from incompatible pointer type` warning after changing `&arr` to `arr`?

Comment: also you need to increase the length of `arr` to 11, cause you need an extra space for the `NUL` terminator.

Comment: I already mentioned I did it wrong because I dont know it in question see

Comment: okay, so is it working now?

Comment: I want to pass arrays to both functions using address. Passing addresses. Otherwise it will never work. What shown in comment it simply passing pointer's by value.

Comment: Pointer value == address.

Comment: @fpiette then why my ret in main remains 0 I am sure returning more than 0. I need populated `array` argument in main. I am not getting it because ret stays 0

Comment: I won't look at partial code. I need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @user786 as fpiette said, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have fixed it its working now posted on code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263719/find-out-pattern-in-string-that-repeats-and-make-the-string